# How to set provisioning profile to Xcode project after fastlane match creation?

Tags: ios, xcode, match, provisioning-profile, fastlane

How can I make Xcode choose the provisioning profile that is saved here with fastlane match : ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

When I open the project with Xcode, it displays the old provisioning profile that I copied the project from but not the ones fastlane match created.

What I'm trying to do is copying a project, updating its content and then sending it to app store autonomously. But I'm stuck at the setting provisioning profiles to Xcode step. I want to do that autonomously. How can I do that?

Comment: Within Xcode, if you have set the correct `Bundle Identifier` in your target's `General` tab, you should be able to select this provisioning profile from the `Signing & Capabilities` tab

Comment: I don't want to open Xcode to do that. I want to set the provisioning profile automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom fastlane lane such as `match_development` where you call match and then you can call [update_project_provisioning](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/update_project_provisioning/) lane.